# Rotate image to 'point' to mouse position

Tags: java, slick2d

I have a gun image on top of a tank image.  I want the gun to point towards the mouse position so the mouse can be used to aim.  The original gun image will be pointing upwards.  I'm using Slick2D and it's image class has a rotate function that takes an angle.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the location of the user's mouse by asking an Input object. This is done by asking the GameContainer for the input.

```
Input userInput = gameContainer.getInput();
float mouseX = userInput.getMouseX();
float mouseY = userInput.getMouseY();
```

The locations of the mouse and the gun can be used to determine the angle the gun needs to face. We can imagine drawing a line between the gun and the mouse and finding the angle of this line. This angle is the angle the gun needs to face in order to 'point' towards the mouse.

```
Vector2f gunLocation = gun.getLocation();
float xDistance = mouseX - gunLocation.x;
float yDistance = mouseY - gunLocation.y;
double angleToTurn = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance));
gunImage.setRotation((float)angleToTurn);
```

Comment: Thanks, I put the code into my game and it sort of worked.  The gun does rotate, but only at half the speed of me moving the mouse, and when I move the mouse to the other side of the gun it starts rotating the other way.  Do you know what could of gone wrong?

Comment: Interesting. This is essentially a code snippet from my own game so I am fairly certain it works. Are you certain you are using Math.atan2? I only ask because Math.atan has a range of [pi/2, -pi/2] whereas Math.atan2 has a range of [pi, -pi]

Comment: Here is the code in my Tank class' update function: http://pastebin.com/KsQUWdEr  I have declared an instance of this class and call this method in the update section of my gameplay state.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error. I used the following to perform my test: http://pastebin.com/iFjaxNs1 I have an instance of this class with the update method called every update and the draw method called on render.

Comment: I ran your test and got the same result: the gun/image does move in the expected direction but at a different speed to the mouse.  At some points it is slower and then suddenly speeds up to face the mouse.

Comment: Just found out the mistake: the image I was using was too big, and the mouse was moving inside it which confused it :D Found a smaller one and it works great.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help

Comment: I've found that the rotation is a bit off which I can fix by subtracting 32 from both mouseX and mouseY when I call Math.atan2.  Is this normal or has something in my code messed up the mouse co-ords?

Comment: I have not had any problems with image rotation, certainly no problems with mouseX and mouseY being off by a constant shift. Your rotation problems may be a result of the fact that the centre of rotation for an Image in Slick is the top left corner of the image. Have you tried to see if your 'fix' works for different sized images?

Answer (score 1):

**The aiming is done like this:**

The direction from the tank to the mouse is like:

```
float deltaX = mouse.x - tank.x;
float deltaY = mouse.y - tank.y;

// The resulting direction
return (int) (360 + Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX))) % 360;
```

Just update the direction of the tank to the current mouse position e.g. in the `mouseMoved` event.

**Rotating the image:**

Have a look at stack overflow or the java doc: `"Graphics2D", "affine transform", "translation"`. Maybe your engine already provides some library functions.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To build on the above answer..

Because the y-axis is decreasing try:

```
float deltaX = mouse.x - tank.x;
float deltaY = tank.y - mouse.y;
```