# Java: rotating image so that it points at the mouse cursor

Tags: java, image, swing, rotation, awt

I want the player image to point towards the mouse cursor. I use this code to get the postion of the mouse cursor:

```
private int cursorX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
private int cursorY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
```

**Note:** The default player image points upwards

Comment: rotating an image implicates moving it from its axis without changing its position, thats not what you want to do tho, you want to move the image to the same position as the cursor?

Comment: no, I want the players image to face the mouse cursor

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use [trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) in order to calculate the angle of rotation. For that you'll first need to obtain the location of the image and the cursor.  I cannot tell you how to get the position for the image as this may vary. For this example (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461993/rotate-image-to-point-to-mouse-position/10462226#10462226)), I'll assume `imageX` and `imageY` are the `x` and `y` positions of your image:

```
float xDistance = cursorX - imageX;
float yDistance = cursorY - imageY;
double rotationAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance));
```

Comment: how would I implement this in g2D.drawImage(image,x,y,this) so that it draws the rotated image instead of the default or would I implement it in some other way?

Comment: use `.rotate(rotationAngle);`

Comment: The image class im using doesn't have a .rotate

Comment: `ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Player.png");
image = ii.getImage();`

Comment: I'm not really sure that I'm doing it right because when I write it in the paint method like this `double theta = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(cursorY - player.getY(), cursorX - player.getX()));
        if(player.isAlive()){
            g2D.rotate(theta);
            g2D.drawImage(player.getImage(),player.getX(),player.getY(),this);
        }` Both the enemy and the player faces 45 degrees all the time and they move really fast in a circle shape, both move up when i press w or d and they move down if I press s or a

Comment: I have the paint method in a different class than the player class and it is used for both the player and the enemy. I don't know if that would make any differance

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28614/discussion-between-fiskpotatis-and-mr-d)

Comment: @Fiskpotatis I suggest you modify this a little and move it to the [game development site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). Its more like the type of question they are used to

Answer (score 2):

To find the angle from a coordinate (0,0) to another coordinate (x,y), we can use the trigonometric function tan^-1(y/x).

Java's [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class specifies a static method `atan2` which acts as a tan^-1 function (also known as "arctangent", hence "atan") and returns the angle in *radians*. (There is a method `atan` which takes one argument. See the linked Javadoc.)

In order to find the angle in degrees from the coordinate of your "player" to the coordinate of the mouse cursor, (I'll assume this "player" you make mention of has x and y coordinates), we need to do something like this:

```
double theta = Math.atan2(cursorY - player.getY(), cursorX - player.getX());
```

It is also of note that an angle of zero radians would indicate that the mouse is directly to the *right* of the player. You mention that the "default player image" points upwards; if you mean that before rotation, your image faces upward for the player, it would be more conventional to geometry and the Java implementation of `atan2` to have your player face right "by default".

Comment: Should I create a class that extends Math.atan2 and use that or did you mean to write `theta = Math.atan2`? How would I implement this in my `g2D.drawImage(image,x,y,this);`, am I supposed to implement it in some other way?

Comment: My mistake. Yes, you can find the angle by writing `Math.atan2(...)`. It is a static method. I edited my answer to reflect that.

You wouldn't (and couldn't) write a class that extends `Math.atan2`. 

For use with Graphics2D, you can call the method `g2D.rotate(theta)`, _then_ draw your image.

Comment: atan2() returns radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Though this was asked two years ago...

If you need the mouse to keep updating the mouse position in the window, see [mouseMotionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html). The current you use to get the mouse position is relative to the whole screen. Just keep that in mind.

Otherwise, here is a method I use,

```
public double angleInRelation(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    // Point 1 in relation to point 2
    Point point1 = new Point(x1, y1);
    Point point2 = new Point(x2, y2);
    int xdiff = Math.abs(point2.x - point1.x);
    int ydiff = Math.abs(point2.y - point1.y);
    double deg = 361;
    if ( (point2.x > point1.x) && (point2.y < point1.y) ) {
        // Quadrant 1
        deg = -Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.toRadians(ydiff) / Math.toRadians(xdiff)));

    } else if ( (point2.x > point1.x) && (point2.y > point1.y) ) {
        // Quadrant 2
        deg = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.toRadians(ydiff) / Math.toRadians(xdiff)));

    } else if ( (point2.x < point1.x) && (point2.y > point1.y) ) {
        // Quadrant 3
        deg = 90 + Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.toRadians(xdiff) / Math.toRadians(ydiff)));

    } else if ( (point2.x < point1.x) && (point2.y < point1.y) ) {
        // Quadrant 4
        deg = 180 + Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.toRadians(ydiff) / Math.toRadians(xdiff)));

    } else if ((point2.x == point1.x) && (point2.y < point1.y)){
        deg = -90;
    } else if ((point2.x == point1.x) && (point2.y > point1.y)) {
        deg = 90;
    } else if ((point2.y == point1.y) && (point2.x > point1.x)) {
        deg = 0;
    } else if ((point2.y == point2.y) && (point2.x < point1.x)) {
        deg = 180;
    }
    if (deg == 361) {
        deg = 0;
    }
    return deg;
}
```

In words, you get the angle of each of the θs as shown in the picture below and check if x or y are 0 and make a special case for that.

The origin is the middle of the picture and each of the points (marked with a hand-drawn cross) is where the mouse position is.

[image: picture in relation to mouse position]